# Cannot Find Element by Id? Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium on this site(https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html)

here is the code I use

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html")

driver.find_element_by_id("emailOrNickname")
```

but I keep getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="emailOrNickname"]"}
```

Comment: url is not valid

Comment: Using `name` attribute instead of id may solve your problem.

Comment: @madogan same problem,

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('input', {'id': 'emailOrNickname'})`
```

Comment: ```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Edited, but requires BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

I think this website detects selenium. Because I can reach the site with normal browser but selenium does not show anything at login or register page. You need to bypass it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  If you look at the response headers from the site you will see

```
server: rhino-core-shield
```

This is an indication that the server could be protected by a web application firewall.

If you inspect what you're actually getting back from the website using

```
driver.page_source
```

you will see that you're not actually getting the login page you expected, instead you are getting a horrible pile of Javascript which will presumably redirect to the real login page.  The upshot is that this particular website's login page is going to be quite difficult to access programatically.

Answer (score 0):

please use following xpath to click and sendkeys to email field

```
 driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id="emailOrNickname"]");
```